# nginx proxy: add ${host} to proxied url

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I need to use `nginx-1.6.2` as a reverse-proxy in a multinamed vhost, where the actual `host`-name (as reported by the client) becomes part of the proxy URL.

Basically I would like to do a mapping

- `http://example.com/test/foo/bar` -> `http://backend.local:8000/example.com/portal/foo/bar`
- `http://test.example.com/test/ping/pong` -> `http://backend.local:8000/test.example.com/portal/ping/pong`

I tried using `${http_host}` and `${host}` in the `proxy_pass` directive:

```
server {
    server_name example.com *.example.com;
    listen 80;
    location /test {
        proxy_pass http://backend.local:8000/${host}/portal/
    }
}
```

But either gives me a `502: Bad Gateway` error, when I access e,g. `http://example.com/test/fnurz`

If I replace `${host}` with a fixed string (e.g. `example.com`) it works as expected, but obviously the proxy hen gets the same URL for both `http://example.com/test/fnurz` and `http://x.example.com/test/fnurz`, which is what I try to avoid.

Comment: What do the nginx debug logs tell you is happening with the request processing?

Comment: @womble hmm thanks: `no resolver defined to resolve backend.local`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after a close inspection of the debug logs, it turned out that nginx could not *resolve* the `backend.local` hostname.

adding a line:

```
resolver 192.168.144.120; # IP of the local DNS server
```

resolved the issue.

However, it is unclear to me why the nginx fails resolve a `proxy_pass` *with* a variable, when it succeeds just fine *without* any variable.

Comment: Because without a variable, nginx can resolve the address at startup (because it knows the name won't change), whereas with a variable it needs to do the resolution at runtime (which it won't do unless you configure a resolver).  It's a limitation of nginx (which you could submit a patch for, if you liked) that it doesn't recognise that the variable isn't in the host part of the URL.